# Rails One-One Relationship- Foreign Key Location

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models, address and country.  Address contains basic address info (line1,line2,city,etc.) and has a one to one relationship with a country.

The countries table is read-only, I don't want it change.

I have the forms creating a *country_id* column in the "addresses" table, but it's looking for *address_id* in the country table.

How do I tell rails to use the *country_id* in the addresses table to lookup a country?

Here is what the models look like:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :consultant
   has_one :country
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :country   
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :address
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) documentation:

> This method should only be used if this class contains the foreign key.

So your code should be:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_to :consultant
  belongs_to :country
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :country   
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  I also had to add ":primary_key => :country_id" to Address to get it to work.